# How to debug slow https connections?

Tags: curl, networking

Our develop team frequently goes into  network problem when visiting our website https://m.beta.joudou.com in our office. (Sometime it is quick, but it will happen for many times when it is slow which will add up to several hours.)

The Chrome devtools shows a very long `initial connection` when visiting our website's html.

[image]

We tried `curl -v` the page at the same time when the website is slow.
It stucks after printing the line `* TCP_NODELAY set`.

```
10437 ± : curl -v https://m.beta.joudou.com                                 ⏎ [6d6h56m] ✹
* Rebuilt URL to: https://m.beta.joudou.com/
*   Trying 123.57.59.177...
* TCP_NODELAY set
<--- The command stuck here for a very long time
* Connected to m.beta.joudou.com (123.57.59.177) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: m.beta.joudou.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Basic DV SSL CA - G1
* Server certificate: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: m.beta.joudou.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
```

The problem has not yet be detected when outside our office, which means it only happens when we are using the network in our office. We have changed the `TP-Link` adapter and even have changed the ISP, the problem remains.

Are there any suggestions for me to detect the problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: You can add `--trace-time` to the curl command line to get a detailed time stamp on each verbose output line. But the time before `Connected` is quite simply curl waiting for the TCP connection phase to complete!

Comment: Does this mean there may be some problem with the network from my office to the server? And the slow is probably not because of some problem with our server?

Comment: It means something makes the TCP handshake very slow.

Comment: I'm facing a very similar problem; has anyone come across a solution yet?

Comment: Sounds like you might have routing problems.

Comment: Hope this article https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-question-of-timing/ is helping